# Why does This table have vertical lines (booktabs, tabularx)

Tags: tabularx, booktabs

[image]I would like to have this table just with horizontal lines (which was the case just using the table package).

```
  \begin{cframed}[gray!35]

\vspace{-4mm}
\begin{table}[H]
    \scriptsize
    \Tables
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
        & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ \cmidrule[.5pt](r){2-2}\cmidrule[.5pt](r){3-3}\cmidrule[.5pt](r){4-4}\cmidrule[.5pt](r){5-5}\cmidrule[.5pt](r){6-6}\cmidrule[.5pt](r){7-7}\cmidrule[.5pt](r){8-8}                                                                         
        
        % Einträge Tabelle 4
        
        Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\  
        
        Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
        
        Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\    
        
        
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

\end{cframed}

Comment: Remove the `|` parts from the argument to `tabularx`.

Comment: Thank you! Helped me a lot.